# extra space under div contained within footer

Tags: html, css

I am working on my first website and its very basic code, but
the div "beyza", on the website (on the image) its the text "Site designed by Beyza" in my footer, keeps showing extra space under, how can I resolve the issue? [here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny7Y4.png)

**Many thanks in advance!**

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  width: %100;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
.instagram {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
footer small {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
.sponsor {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.beyza {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFF;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="instagram">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alix.bizet/">
        <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="instagram">
      </a>
    </div>
    <small>&copy; 2016 Hair by Hood Project </small>

    <div class="sponsor">
      <a href="http://designmuseum.org">
        <img src="images/DesMus2.png" alt="designmuseum">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="beyza">Site designed by Beyza @<a href="https://graphicdialogue.co">GRAPHIC DIALOGUE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-bottom from .sponsor class

```
.sponsor {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 15px;
 ->margin-bottom: 15px;
 display: block;
```

}

Comment: There's still some space under `.beyza` if the margin on `.sponsor` is removed. What if OP wants `.sponsor` and `.beyza` to share a baseline?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `sponsor` higher just add `width: 100%` to sponsor.

You can also wrap `sponsor` and `beyza` in another `div` element and make it:
`display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between,
align-items: flex-start;`

- remove `margin-bottom` from sponsor
- add `align-self: flex-end` to `beyza`

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP is going to want `.sponsor` and `.beyza` share a baseline.

Comment: then just remove `margin-bottom` from `sponsor` element as @user2693928 pointed out

Comment: Possibly, in the linked image the image in `.sponser` is about twice the height of the text in `.beyza`. Removing the margin won't change that. Guess we'll have to wait for some feedback from OP to know for sure.

Comment: Try with wrapping element as I described above. I replaced sponsor image to show that its size doesn't matter http://codepen.io/niemaszoka/pen/GNjYEg (notice that I removed `float` property those two elements inside)

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues here:

1. you missed your closing anchor

   `<a href="https://graphicdialogue.co">GRAPHIC DIALOGUE</div>`
2. typo

   `.container{width: %100}`
3. adjustmargin-bottom

   `.sponsor {
     float: left;
     padding-left: 15px;
     margin-bottom: 15px; //this is the problem-try reduce the size
     display: block;
   }`